# Android Studio Gradle Analyse is broken

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

The gradle tools of Android Studio who highlight third party when there is update (see screenshot below).

[image: Gradle in AS 1.3.1]

Doesn't work on Android Studio v1.4 (Doesn't highlight when there is a new version).

I try to remove ".gradle" folder, reset cache and settings under "File->Invalidate Caches / Restart" of Android Studio, re-download AS 1.4  but still nothing.

I then open my project with Android Studio 1.3.1 and the library was perfectly highlighted (Ex: com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.8.0 show 8.1.0).

Not sure if it's bug, or configuration issue. 
My project build.gradle look like :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.8.0' 
}
```

And the top level  :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: It shows there's new version of library if you have already downloaded it. You can check SDK Manager in AS 1.4 if you do have downloaded latest version of play-services (just in case if AS 1.4 and AS 1.3 are looking at different source directories on your computer).

Comment: Everything is up to date in SDK Manager (SDK tools/platform->r24.4/r23.0.1, Android Support Repository/library ->r22/r23.0.1, play services->r27, google repo->r22). Even when I downgrade Gradle to a previous version AS 1.4 doesn't ask for new version. @Sharj by downgrading play services to 7.8.0 does AS 1.4 ask you for update after sync ?

Comment: Yes, It does show on my AS 1.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Sharj, he was right, there was some conflict from previous AS.

I got it to work, by doing the following :

- Delete all AndroidStudio* folder from ~/Library/Application Support (Forgot to say I'm using mac os)
- Delete my SDK folder.
- Download AS as new again, start the startup installation, then he download the SDK by himself.

Then working!